find the maximum value of the following multivariable function
I am looking at the following function
$$\cos(x-a) - \cos(y-a) + \cos(x-b) + \cos(y-b)$$
for which I want to find the maximum. Numerically maximizing this function yields a number that looks a lot like $2\sqrt{2}$. Probably this is also the maximum, but I don't see right away how to prove it. If someone has a hint on how to approach this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Is this a function of just $x$ and $y$ or a function of $x$, $y$, $a$, and $b$?

its a function of all the variables x,y,a and b

@etotheipi Just to be sure, $a,b$ are not given, right?

correct, its a function of 4  variables

Does this answer your question? Solving a system of simultaneous trigonometric equations to find maxima of 4-D scalar field - found using an Approach0 search. Note rearranging your function to be $\cos(x-b)+\cos(x-a)+\cos(y-b)-\cos(y-a)$ we see it corresponds to $A=x$, $B=b$, $C=y$ & $D=a$ in my proposed duplicate question.

I can't believe this was asked before, this is amazing

Using trigonometric identities,  $$  \cos{(x-a)}+\cos{(x-b)} = 2\cos{\left(x-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)}\cos{\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)}, $$ $$ \cos{(y-b)}-\cos{(y-a)}\big) =  2\sin{\left(y-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)}\sin{\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)}. $$ Therefore, to maximize the sum, we need to maximize
$$ 2\left[ \cos{\left(x-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)}\cos{\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)} + \sin{\left(y-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)}\sin{\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)}\right]. $$
One way to maximize it, is to choose values of $x(a,b)$ and $y(a,b)$ such that the respective values of cos and sin are $1$, leaving us with $$2\left[ \cos{\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)} +\sin{\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)}\right].$$
Maxmimiming this results in $2\sqrt{2}$ as you suggest.
